# Is crystal reports dead?

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports

We have a developer with Crystal Reports experience, and some new reports that need to be written for a WinForm application accessing data from a SQL Server in the network.

An external consultant has made the comment that "Crystal Reports is dead" and to forget about it and install SQL Reporting Services instead.

Is this a reasonable proposition? Is the learning curve required for the developer to get the job done going to provide some significant improvement to the report generation process over Crystal?

Comment: "Crystal Reports is dead [amongst freelance developers and those who have the option to choose a reporting engine, ran on top of SQL Server or ODBC.]"   There.  I fixed that statement for your consultant.  The answers mentioned below are quite correct.  However, until about 7-8 years ago, CR was the only reasonable choice that you had to use when it came to enterprise-level report design.  But CR can be a horrible pain in the arse to work with and if you can switch to SSRS, you probably should.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As any other question like this, the answer will come with some level of passion.

In the company that I work for, we use the Business Objects BI suite. And Crystal Reports is part of this suite. And we use it a lot.

Business Objects was acquired by SAP, so it is the "dafault" choice for SAP users, that if it's not the 1st ERP vendor, it's the second, and, in this case, the number one is Oracle, and I doubt that Oracle will recomend SQL reporting services...

So, in my opinion, this external consultant is very biased and isn't seeing the big picture. Ok, the crystal usage among developers will decline, but claim that will be dead is a little bit to much.

Comment: The external consultant was biased but as one of many developers who has had some pain with the integration of Crystal, he or she may have really intended to push the choice away from Crystal Reports. This doesn't excuse bias in the answer, it's just my guess as to why they claimed it was "dead."

Comment: personally I also doubt that Oracle will recommend Crystal Reports.

Comment: @Andrey - absolutely. The only thing Oracle *ever* recommends is giving more money to Oracle.

Answer (score 18):

**Is this good advice?**

*Is SSRS worth the learning curve in terms of a payoff from the change?*

Well worth it, on several levels.

1. It's cheaper to deploy in terms of licensing.
2. It's much more robust. Your developers will stop resisting change for fear of breaking something.
3. It's a lot faster (subject to the efficiency of the backing SQL)
4. Your developers will be happier. CR wages are high for the same reason sewage workers are well paid.
5. It's extensible. Doing this requires a higher level of expertise but it gives you a lot of options.

Items 1-4 directly affect the cost of ownership. CR is a bottomless pit of maintenance costs.

As to the learning curve,

- The general principles of operation are the same
- SSRS is simpler to understand because it is more internally consistent
- Developer reactions are polarised into "Urgh, it's different" and "Thank god for that"

**Why did the consultant make a sweeping, emotionally charged statement like that?**

Your consultant went over the top for a very good reason.

CR is unreliable, expensive and difficult to use. Simple bugs have gone uncorrected for decades after being publicly documented. Telephone support is expensive and in my experience worthless. Different versions are incompatible to the point of breaking each other. The internal query engine produces incorrect results.

If it isn't dead then it should be. I will cheerfully swing the hammer if your consultant holds the stake. Afterwards we should cut off the head and stuff the mouth with garlic because otherwise some imbecile in management will read a glossy brochure and inflict it on us again.

Managers are like children: the idea is too complex for them. If your consultant gave a comprehensive and considered assessment, the only thing they would remember is that he talked a lot about CR. This would lead to inappropriate decision making, so he simplified it to sneering, which is something they can understand and remember.

Two upvotes and two downvotes. Very telling. Political correctness is not useful. Lie to others if it helps, but never lie to yourself.

Crystal Reports has a very high cost of ownership, both capital and ongoing, but discussions of a topic like this rapidly degenerate into religious wars, and people lose sight of the facts.

- The people who buy it aren't the people who have to use it.
- The marketing material is *marketing material* which is as close to lies as the law permits.
- A detailed consideration is lengthy and technical, well beyond both the capability of decision makers.
- Faced with decisions they can't handle, bureaucrats in business and government alike use a standard blame evasion tactic: they do what everyone else did, no matter how stupid.

Comment: Downvoters, if you think I am wrong perhaps you might say why. Otherwise you lack credibility.

Comment: Here's an upvote... You couldn't imagine my relief when I first started using SSRS when it came out... Bloody hell if I'm ever going back to CR... No way!!!

Comment: I hear that story a lot. The only IT professional I ever met who *likes* CR is (get ready for this) my girlfriend. I think the DBs from which she reports are so bizarrely convoluted that the defects of CR disappear into the general mayhem.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2010/04/08/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2010.aspx

Looks like Microsoft aren't bundling it any more, which may well mean there will be a decline in its popularity.

Comment: ... but it's still available for free, and that doesn't mean it's worse than SSRS or harder to use?

Comment: That's true. My point was more that people may look at alternatives and that there may have been some disagreement between Microsoft and SAP. It may just have been that crystal reports wasn't ready when they wanted to release VS2010.